# Find probability of odd number will follow an even number

Tags: probability

> A fair dice is rolled twice.the probability that an odd number will follow an even number?

There may be so many cases are possible. But if I consider only 2 number, e.g., 3,6 then required probability is 1/2. Is it right?

Comment: Hint:  You need the first die to be even and the second to be odd; two independent events.

Comment: `so many cases are possible` - not really, only $9$ (out of $36$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you question means, or what it *intended* to ask. So I will answer the two questions I have in mind.

Let $E$ be the event that you roll and even number, $O$ for odd. Then one question is what is the probability that you get the sequence $EO$.
I will not assume independence, but instead construct a table.

The rows are the first roll, the columns are the second roll. Check marks indicate success.
\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|c|c}
EO& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6\\\hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
2&\checkmark& &\checkmark& & \checkmark& \\\hline
3 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
4&\checkmark& &\checkmark& & \checkmark& \\\hline
5 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
6&\checkmark& &\checkmark& & \checkmark& 
\end{array}

I only assume that all pairs are equally likely. I count and get $9/36 = 1/4$.

Now you can try and assume independence and get the same answer.

The other question I had in mind was $P(O|E)$.

Using the previous answer I get 
$$P(O|E) = \frac{P(EO)}{P(E)} = \frac{1/4}{3/6} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Use independence and arrive at the same thing.